# Journey Builder decision splits not working as expected

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I have been working on the Journey Builder and I am using Salesforce (Lead) event as entry source. I have used a three entry criteria and based on that a data extension is been created automatically.  Once the data enters into journey, there is a wait time of 10 mins and again checking.  If still the data satisfies the entry condition and i am checking with contact data since the journey data doesn't change.  But the decision splits are not working as expected. Sometimes it works and most of the time its not working.  It is something weird.  Can anyone help me in this?  I don't know where i am going wrong.

[image: Automatically created relationship]
[image: journey builder entry criteria]
[image: Using contact data to check if the records still satisfy the condition]

Comment: @adam can you give me any suggestion on the above issue?

Comment: It could be a timing issue that updates from salesforce are syncing a little bit after the decision split check. Try sending a new lead and then immediately update it and then wait for 5 mins.